# Can I deactivate buttons/edittexts from my layout? (visible but deactivated)

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout with a spinner and a lot of textboxes and buttons.

I need to make appear some elements of the layout when one of the options of the spinner is selected and to make disappear when other is selected. ----> PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

But also, I need to deactivate some elements of the layout. I mean that they have to be visible, but the user can't press buttons or edit edittext's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Assuming you have a handle to your layout you can do smth like this:

```
yourLayoutToShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

or

```
yourLayoutToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

**UPDATE**:

To get a handle to your layout (the one you want to show/hide dynamically) you need to do smth like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    LinearLayout viewToShowOrHide = 
        (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_to_show_or_hide);
}
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot it works! but i have another question now...  ¿it is possible to deactivate the buttons and edditboxes? i mean.. to have they visible but deactivated. I mean that the user can't press buttons or write textedits

Comment: Try to use `View.setEnabled(boolean enabled)`. The effect depends on actual View subclass. So just try, however I think it should work for Buttons and Checkboxes as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a control by doing ...

```
myControl.setEnabled(false);
```